# Most secure way to send variables with php

Tags: php, android, mysql, security, variables

I'm new to PHP code and I wanted to know if I'm coding the right way. I need to send data from my android app to my server. I'm now doing it with php. (Is this the right way? if not, what should I use for this?)

So if I pass them to my server it is like this:

```
www.myserverexample.com/myPhpScript.php?variable1=text1&variable2=text2
```

it seems like this is not the right way. and what if I need to send 20 variables to the server, is this still allright, it seems like this is not realy secure to do.

(all validation on correct variables is done in the php script and then send to my database)

Comment: In a word, no - that's the most unsecure way to pass data.

Comment: That is what I thought, but what do you suggest I use then?

Comment: If you are handling user input use prepared statements with either mysqli or PDO

Comment: You need to post the data back, and still there's a lot more to security than just that.

Comment: Besides GET being less secure, you have to consider the query string length limit if you send larger amounts of data through GET.

Comment: GET is only less secure if you are using a shared server, which is pretty not secure anyways

Comment: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use HTTPS. There are at least 3 organizations now that you can get free certificates from. Both GET and POST variables are protected when using HTTPS.
2. Are you going to be using shared hosting or dedicated hosting? In what way are you going to secure your web server logs? How sensitive or personal are the values in these variables? We need to know this before we can decide if GET is secure or not, as the entire URL is logged.
3. Do the values change anything on the server? Like update a database or file? If that's the case, you should use POST.

GET is fine if you control your own web server logs (ie, not shared hosting) and the values are not particularly sensitive. Else use POST.

Answer (score -1):

you are using the GET method.
this works but is not secure and not how you should send any sensitive data
if you need to send data to the server securely
you need to use the POST method over SSL

Comment: If you're using SSL, GET vs POST are equally secure.  GET is only a security risk if the URL is visible, like in a browser (where its in the address bar).  Using GET programatically is as safe as POST.  Just make sure to use HTTPS.

Comment: `Using GET programatically is as safe as POST`. Server logfiles contain all parameters of a GET request.

Comment: And if an outside attacker has access to your server's logfiles, you have other issues.

Answer (score -1):

In this instance, I suggest you use a POST request to send your  data to the php script. With POST, there is no limit on how much data you can send in the HTTP content body (the maximum length for a query string in a GET request is 2KB I think), and your variables are a bit more hidden because they are not exposed in the query string.

If you switch to using POST, then you will need to change all the `$_GET` variables to `$_POST` in your php script, and somehow set the `content-type` request header to `x-www-url-form-encoded` in your app.

Mind you, if you want to prevent MITM attacks and improve overall security - use SSL.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "and somehow set the content-type request header to x-www-url-form-encoded in your app. Mind you,"

Comment: I meant change the HTTP header `content-type` to `x-www-url-form-encoded` so php passes your form variables to the $_POST variable.

Comment: "no limit" is irrelevant. wireshark can see POST data too.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Oh well, it looks like SSL is the best option.

Answer (score -2):

Sending data between client (android-app) and server (php web application) can be done many ways.

Most known way is https protocol but before we dig in to that you should be familiar with **HTTP** Methods!

what your using right now is **GET** Method which sends data through url and its visible to everyone so obviously its **NOT** secure!

You most use **POST** method to solve this!

And then consider using **HTTPS** certification because it encrypt your data so it could not be stolen

Comment: YES! indeed this is what I was looking for!

Comment: GET actually isn't insecure.  Its using HTTPS instead of HTTP that matters for security.  GET vs POST is only a security issue when going to a site in a browser, not when used as a programmatic endpoint.

Comment: @GabeSechan it is insecure because you can sniff data packets and their routes using tools like BurpSuit! ;)

Comment: @hamidrezabstn Not if you're using HTTPS.  Its the encryption that protects you, not the fact you're using POST instead of GET.

Comment: @GabeSechan using **GET** instead of **POST** is minimum requirement but not enough ! as i said he should use **HTTPS** for security reasons!

Comment: And I'm saying you have it backwards. Https is all that matters for security. Post vs get only matters if the url is typed in. You don't actually know what you're talking about, and are spouting   1990s era misinformation

Comment: @GabeSechan come on man your insulting ! ok smart ass you know everything ! cheers!

Comment: I know more than you on this.  HTTPS is encryption.  It encrypts everything, including the URL.  This means its secure to most outside attacks (things like MITM may still work).  POST is not encrypted.  Anyone who can see the packet can read it with a simple wire sniffer-  as simple as putting their network card into promiscuous mode.  It provides no protection.  The idea its more secure comes from the fact that if you go to a page in a browser you can see GET parameters but not POST ones in the address bar.  Which is something to consider for a webpage, but for a webservice doesn't matter.

Comment: So there were a lot of people in the late 90s and early 2000s who advocated POST over GET for security reasons.  They weren't 100% wrong, but their reasons don't matter for webservices, and even then they weren't really secure without encryption-  just secure from accidentally copy pasting a URL with their info in it.  Which is good for webpages and again doesn't matter for a webservice endpoint.  Note that most RESTful frameworks use GET to get an object and POST to update one.  Because it actually isn't any less secure, they use the verb to differentiate function.

Comment: @GabeSechan i answer the question based on my experience and information ! maybe they are not complete but in fact they were not completly wrong! you should say these two last comments as answer so others can use it instead of insulting ! i upvote your comments so others can use it! thanks for sharing your knowledge! cheers!

Comment: @hamidrezabstn The problem is that your answer *is* completely wrong. Choosing GET or POST has **nothing to do with security**. Nothing at all. GET/POST and "security" should never be used in the same sentence; security is not a consideration at all when choosing POST over GET.